# How to set input mapping for all requests, not just application/json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Looking at the examples for `AWS API Gateway` in order to map a querystring to the `Lambda` function it shows examples of creating a template map for `application/json` in the integration request. How do I create a template for all requests no matter the `Content-Type`? I want it to fire the `Lambda` with the querystring params regardless of the `Content-Type` in the request.

Comment: This may not be currently possible. Did you try using some wildcard for the content type header? Something like `Content-Type: *`

Comment: I tried */* ... but I'll try your suggestion

Comment: There may be some regex expression to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible at the moment. There is no documented wild card available.

"application/json" is the default content type. This is used if no content type is specified in the request (source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=215471).